# OSX Bash/Shell: How to pass/use "<", ">" (as Symbol/Char) and "\n" in Terminal command line?

Tags: ios, bash, shell, command-line, pipe

I have a small OSX Bash/Shell script, when run it creates a new file and saves the given UserName from command line as String in a plist file.

With my command "CreateUser":

`$ CreateUser -Name Cyborg`

I get this plist file saved successfully:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>Cyborg</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to extend this plist file so I can add PhoneNumer below UserName but unfortunately cant edit the source code since it's a compiled binary file.

#### A solution I came up with by extend my command:

```
$ CreateUser -Name "Cyborg</string><key>PhoneNumber</key><string>0987654321"
```

And I get this results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>Cyborg&lt;/string&gt;&lt;key&gt;PhoneNumber&lt;/key&gt;&lt;string&gt;0987654321</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

#### The problem the Terminal don't like `<`, `>` or `\n` :(

Is there a way to get passed `<` and `>` instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;`?
I also tried to get new line with `"\n"` but it didnt work.
I tried `<<<EOF` without luck.

---

#### Desired result:

It would be great if I could get result like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>Cyborg</string>
    <key>PhoneNumber</key>
    <string>0987654321</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here is some of info which I can read from **command** "CreateUser" binary file:

```
lowercaseStringnewlengthcharacterAtIndex:appendBytes:length:isEqualToString:allocinitWithData:encoding:autoreleasedataUsingEncoding:base64EncodedStringWithOptions:standardUserDefaultsvalueForKey:stringWithFormat:defaultManagerfileExistsAtPath:initWithContentsOfFile:initsetObject:forKey:writeToFile:atomically:componentsSeparatedByString:objectAtIndex:stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:UserInfo%@Name/savefile/UserInfo.plistUserName;    UserInfoXML =
```

#### The question:

Is there a way to make a `pipe` , `cat`, `echo` etc or any other option to get deired results with my command?

Thanks a million, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What ever tool you're using for generating the plist is correctly escaping the data that's being passed in as it expects it to be a single property. I'd wildly guess that you're doing `plutil -insert "Username" -string 'username'`. Without access to the code, it's very hard to offer any form of solution; but you're probably better off adding the items as extra 'key, value' pairs as parameters to the CreateUser command

Comment: @Petesh I updated question and added some code from command. Not sure how it adds the name. The plist results I get now with `&lt;` is this a valid plist? Or plist readers will say invalid plist cause of `&lt;` instead of `<`?

Comment: The extra information from the command CreateUser doesn't help - it looks like objective-c selector data (i.e. code in the command). It's using the standard APIs for writing property lists; which means that it will escape the xml data before putting it into the property list which is where the `&lt;` data comes from - you need to escape `<` in order to use it in XML as data.

Comment: You are trying to inject XML into your data, and `CreateUser` is correctly preventing you from doing that. Stop treating it as arbitrary text to modify as you please.

Comment: @chepner How to stop treating it as arbitrary text? Any sample? Can I save my data (PhoneNumber) to a txt file or assign as an alias and then inject it to CreateUser? Thank you.